# How can I dynamically update values in an object state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object, `data`, in my state. I have an array of keys, `keysToUpdate`, and an array of values, `newValues`, to update.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: "",
    address: "",
    email: "",
})

const keysToUpdate = ["firstName", "lastName"];
const newValues = ["Joe", "Smith"];
```

Is there a way to dynamically update the `data` with `setState` even if I don't know what the `fieldsToUpdate` array contains?

Comment: you could set an object field using the [] operator like this:
var s = {
[fieldName]: fieldValue
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, like so:

```js
const newData = {...data}
keysToUpdate.forEach((key, i) => newData[key] = newValues[i])
setData(newData)
```

Comment: This is an even simpler solution, thank you! I sometimes forget that making a clone of the state and then directly mutating the clone is a fine thing to do in React.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I realized how simple of an answer this is. You can simply iterate through the `keysToUpdate` array and call `setData` on each iteration.

```
const updateKeys = (keysToUpdate, newValues) => {
    keysToUpdate.forEach((key, i) => {
        setData(prevData => {
            return {
                ...prevData,
                [key]: newValues[i]
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: you should not use set state inside a loop, not recommended

Comment: Why is this? It seems like the internet thinks setting it in a loop is a problem if you do not use a callback function to update the state (which is problematic, I agree). If a callback is used to update the state, why is this not recommended?

Comment: you would trigger rerender each time you set the state, which is problematic optimization   wise

Answer (score 0):

you could use this concept to figure out a solution for you, this in case you want to update state using input for instance.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: '',
    age:''
});


const onInputChange = ({target:{name, value}}) =>{

    setData({
        ...data,
        [name]: value
    });
    
}
```

Comment: I thought about updating the state with `onChange` for each of the inputs, but I have a multistep form that has bits of `data` on each step. I wanted to update each of those bits of `data` when the user moves to the next step. Thank you for the idea though!